# Compilation error building against binary Bouncy: could not find FastRTPS

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building a few packages against the new Bouncy release and I'm seeing a difference between a binary installation and another one from source. Namely, when I source the installation from source my package builds normally, but when I source the binary one it hits an error. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

The error happens in a call to `rosidl_generate_interfaces`:

```
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
        msg/Test.msg
        srv/Test.srv
        DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
```

The error is:

> CMake Error at
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137
> (message):   Could NOT find FastRTPS
> (missing: FastRTPS_INCLUDE_DIR
> FastRTPS_LIBRARIES) Call Stack (most
> recent call first):
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378
> (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
> /opt/ros/bouncy/share/fastrtps_cmake_module/cmake/Modules/FindFastRTPS.cmake:95
> (find_package_handle_standard_args)
> /opt/ros/bouncy/share/rmw_fastrtps_cpp/cmake/rmw_fastrtps_cpp-extras.cmake:20
> (find_package)
> /opt/ros/bouncy/share/rmw_fastrtps_cpp/cmake/rmw_fastrtps_cppConfig.cmake:30
> (include)
> /opt/ros/bouncy/share/rmw_implementation_cmake/cmake/call_for_each_rmw_implementation.cmake:61
> (find_package)
> /opt/ros/bouncy/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/rosidl_generator_py_get_typesupports.cmake:26
> (call_for_each_rmw_implementation)
> /opt/ros/bouncy/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/rosidl_generator_py_generate_interfaces.cmake:27
> (rosidl_generator_py_get_typesupports)
> /opt/ros/bouncy/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:38
> (include)
> /opt/ros/bouncy/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:169
> (ament_execute_extensions)
> CMakeLists.txt:69
> (rosidl_generate_interfaces)

My sources can be found at https://github.com/ada-ros. The package causing the error is [rosidl_generator_ada](https://github.com/ada-ros/rosidl_generator_ada). It's quite possible I'm doing something wrong in the CMakeLists.txt/package.xml because I'm not entirely confident on my understanding of ROS2 dependency tags. Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296462/compilation-error-building-against-binary-bouncy:-could-not-find-fastrtps/) by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:
For what is worth, after converting all the packages to ament_make build type, the error has gone away

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:
Also I've prepared a small reproducer with the default output of `ros2 pkg create`. I've only added the minimal dependencies from my own package to reproduce the error. Here it is: https://github.com/mosteo/ros2_testcases

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-06**:
Please post your exact steps to reproduce your problem (without the need to guess what you are actually doing in which order).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-06**:
From a brief look the example package doesn't declare the dependencies in the package manifest. See https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/1d80aae3de9b0c03052e13ec04a0c32693b38f61/std_msgs/package.xml for an example package with messages.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2018-07-06**:
Are you using `colcon`? If so, does the error persist after upgrading it?

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:
@DirkThomas, I thought the .xml file wouldn't affect the compilation driven by CMake, if there are missing dependencies there that would be a real mistake on my part. The real case had all dependencies (I think). Adding the ones in your example to this testcase didn't help. Steps I followed: (cont.)

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:\

- Create empty ws/src
- Inside src, $ ros2 pkg create --build-type cmake fail
- Copy my sample msg/srv to ~/ws/src/fail/
- Created trivial ~/ws/src/fail/src/main.c
- Filled CMakeLists.txt with minimal info.
- Verify it builds with bouncy installed from srcs
- Verify it fails with bouncy debs

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:
Man, these comments are not the best! Anyway:

- Both my bouncy binary/source installations are per wiki instructions
- Before each build I open a new terminal, source the proper setup.bash, delete build and install folders

I just updated the testcase to add the deps in the xml, and (...)

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:
(...) fixed a clash between the package name and target, I did not see it until trying with the from source bouncy that does not hit the bug. Now I have tested both a couple of times, binary install fails, from source passes.

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-06**:
@sloretz, I'm using plain "colcon build". I'm using the one that becomes available when sourcing the corresponding bouncy installation.

Sorry for the telegraphic style, these comments without preview are not suited for a detailed discussion I guess.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-06**:
The deps in the xml are used to provide each pkg the appropriate context. If the deps are available in an isolated install space the package is likely going to fail if it doesn't declare the correct dependencies. When using the Debian package (which uses a merged install) that won't be a problem.

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-07**:
Ok, thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following patch to `colcon-ros` should fix the problem: [colcon-ros#23](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/pull/23) . Please try it again after updating the Debian package `python3-colcon-ros` to version 0.2.9-1.

**Update:**

With the above update the build works just fine for any existing message package, e.g. the [common_interfaces](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces) repository.

In your case your [test package](https://github.com/mosteo/ros2_testcases) uses plain CMake rather than `ament_cmake`. While that should work the problem is likely related to that difference.

**Update 2:**

The above patch only affects the build type `ament_cmake` but not plain `cmake`. You can workaround the problem by extending the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` manually: `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$AMENT_PREFIX_PATH:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. An [upcoming patch](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/pull/26) release of colcon-ros should be able to address this.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-07**:
Sorry, same error after upgrading:

```
$ apt policy python3-colcon-ros 
python3-colcon-ros:
Installed: 0.2.9-1

$ which colcon
/usr/bin/colcon

$ rm -rf build install; colcon build
```

error in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/UCbSF67g

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-17**:
The error output is not sufficient to provide any help. How does the package `fail_example` look like? Do you have the FastRTPS Debian package installed (`ros-bouncy-fastrtps`)?

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-18**:
See here for a more complete sequence: https://pastebin.com/wnHpyxMM . This is in another computer, with freshly installed bouncy following debians instructions. You can find the repo for my test package in there. At the end of the sequence are the installed package versions.

**Comment by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on 2018-07-18**:
Thanks for following through.

**Comment by [Laas](https://answers.ros.org/users/41249/laas/) on 2019-05-22**:
Should this still be a bug?

```
python3-colcon-ros:
  Installed: 0.3.10-1
```

I'm building Ros in docker and I still have this issue but `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$AMENT_PREFIX_PATH:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` before building fixes the issue.